# How can I programmatically customize the MediaWiki Visual Editor-extension toolbar?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, visual-editor

Is it possible to hide certain VE ux-components? For example, we don't like/need the license-comment in the Save-dialog (= class "ve-ui-mwSaveDialog-license"). Can we hide it?

And is it possible to customize the menubar of VE? For example hide menu items or add a pulldown menu?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get this done yet? It's possible to edit VisualEditor's CSS, but you have to mess around in it's core files. This makes updating especially troublesome.

Comment: Sort of. Hiding items by using "display:none" in css code skin (MediaWiki:Chameleon.css). And extending by using the OOjs UI library: https://doc.wikimedia.org/oojs-ui/master/js/